# How can separate morning and evening shifts patients with gender wise using SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to separate the morning and evening patient checked-in count gender-wise and also if gender age less then show the Female child and M child on the basis of gender.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(ch.EnteredOn) AS counter, 
    CONVERT(date, ch.EnteredOn) AS sessionDay,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(2), ch.EnteredOn, 108) AS INT) < 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Morning',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(2), ch.EnteredOn, 108) AS INT) >= 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS  'Evening',
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.Gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
    SUM(CASE WHEN p.Gender = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fmale,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, P.DOB, GETDATE()) / 8766 <= 18 
                  AND P.Gender = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MChild,
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(hour, P.DOB, GETDATE()) / 8766 <= 18 
                  AND P.Gender = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS FChild
FROM 
    Patient.CheckIn ch
INNER JOIN
    Patient.Patients P ON ch.PatientId = p.PatientId
GROUP BY
    Ch.EnteredOn
```

I have only three columns like `Gender`, `Time` and `DOB`. Gender id 1 shows the male and Gender id 2 is using for females.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWcOa.png)

Comment: Please help me  I am stuck in this query. I have two tables one is for check in and other is for patient gender/patient details.

Comment: Its easier if you provide a [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with your tables.

Comment: Your solution seems good. What is your problem with it?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47286a/2   here is sqlFiddle. I have combined both table scheme. you can query on this.

Comment: I want to separate morning and evening shift-wise gender types like morning gender types and evening gender types.  I want to two-row, one row for morning shifts and second row for evening shifts

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT convert(date, ch.EnteredOn) AS sessionDay, CAST( CONVERT(CHAR(2), ch.EnteredOn, 108) AS INT) <12 as morning, count(ch.EnteredOn) AS counter
,sum(case when p.Gender=1 Then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Male
,sum(case when p.Gender=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 end) as Fmale
,Sum( case when DATEDIFF(hour,P.DOB,GETDATE())/8766<=18 AND P.Gender=1 Then 1 ELSE 0 end ) as MChiled
,Sum( case when DATEDIFF(hour,P.DOB,GETDATE())/8766<=18 AND P.Gender=2 Then 1 ELSE 0 end ) as FChiled
FROM Patient.CheckIn ch
inner join Patient.Patients P on ch.PatientId=p.PatientId 
Group by Ch.EnteredOn
```

`Group BY` can be

```
Group by convert(date, ch.EnteredOn) AS sessionDay, CAST( CONVERT(CHAR(2), ch.EnteredOn, 108) AS INT) <12
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response

Comment: You are welcome. If it was useful you can check it as good answer. Or You can upvote.

Comment: Actually, I have done with using temp table and Union. But I appreciate your support.

Comment: Use 'union all' if two selects are distinct